# Is the order of files random when using files.list?

Tags: google-drive-api

if I use files.list to generate a list of files for a user will the returned list be identical (ie items and order of items) to a similar call at a later time if no changes/modifications have taken place to the users files?

I'm trying to work out the most efficient way of determining if any changes have taken place to a users google drive contents.  I could do this by using the files.list and comparing the file modification date of a particular file with the previous modification date from a saved files.list result.  An alternative way would be to compare the actual result of files.list (i.e. a direct comparison of the list rather than the files).  Using Python comparing the contents of lists is straightforward but an alternative method would be to shelve the results of files.list, calculate the secure hash of the db file and compare the hash with hash of the most recent files.list result.  This will only work if the result of files.list is identical when no changes haven taken place in a users google drive.

Are the results of files.list unchanged if no changes to a users google drive are made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Are the results of files.list unchanged if no changes to a users google drive are made?"

Whilst in practice, the answer is yes, you should **not** rely on this since it is not part of the documented API contract, and so is liable to break in the future. The changes feed https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes is a better fit for your needs.